# Firebase Crashlytics shows error while building Android APK file using Ionic Cordova

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an APK for android on my Ionic Cordova application and running the following command.

```
ionic cordova build android
```

But the following error is coming.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug' (type 'InjectMappingFileIdTask').
  - In plugin 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin' type 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.InjectMappingFileIdTask' field 'resourceFile' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputFile.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'resourceFile'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'resourceFile'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
```

How can I fix this error?

For convenience I am listing below some dependencies I used.

```
"java": "11.0.17"
"gradle": "7.4.2"
"@angular/cli": "~10.0.5"
"@ionic/angular": "^5.3.5"
"cordova-android": "10.1.2"
```